# Not understanding what the % is doing in Perl

Tags: perl, syntax

I am reviewing a script and I have come across a block that I can't figure out:

```
if ((@ifAliasVals[1])&&(%{@ifAliasVals[0]}))  {

...

}
```

What is the `%{@ifAliasVals[0]}` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (@ifAliasVals[1] && %{ @ifAliasVals[0] })
```

is a bad way of writing

```
if ($ifAliasVals[1] && %{ $ifAliasVals[0] })
```

`%{ EXPR }` is a hash dereference. `%{ EXPR }` is basically the same as `%hash`, but accesses the via a reference rather than its name.

In scalar context, `%hash` returns true iff the hash has any elements, so `%{ $ifAliasVals[0] }` checks if the hash referenced by `$ifAliasVals[0]` has elements.

```
my $hash1_ref = { };
my $hash2_ref = { a => 1 };
say %{ $hash1_ref } ? 'has elements' : 'empty';  # empty
say %{ $hash2_ref } ? 'has elements' : 'empty';  # has elements
```

Comment: As a side note, I'm surprised the indexes are different. `if ($ifAliasVals[0] && %{ $ifAliasVals[0] })` would make more sense. ("If `$ifAliasVals[0]` contains a hash ref, and if the referenced hash has elements, then ...")

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `%{ ... }` treats the expression between the braces as a hash-reference, and dereferences it, giving you the entire hash.

The syntax `@ifAliasVals[0]` returns an *array slice* from the array `@ifAliasVals`.  In this case, the array slice only has one element, and so that would have been better written as `$ifAliasVals[0]`.  In any case, it gives you the first element of the array `@ifAliasVals`.

The entire expression `%{ @ifAliasVals[0] }` therefore interprets the first element of `@ifAliasVals` as a hash reference, dereferencing it, yielding the contents of that hash.

In the context of your if-statement above, the right-hand of the `&&` will be true if the hash has any elements, and will be false if the hash is empty.